# Плагин Joomla для мета тэгов

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Всем привет, может кто подскажет нормальный плагин для Joomla 3.6 , который позволяет в рамках создания материала изменять :
Название ссылки на материал;
H1
Title
Description и остальные   мета    данные.
Спасибо!

Comment: а "из коробки" разве нет такой возможности в Joomla?

Comment: В том то и дело, что не вижу, что странно . Можно указать только заголовок http://prntscr.com/dj2gvx и дескрипшен, а вот разграничить заголовок h1, title, ссылка с другим названием на материал, я этого найти не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании статьи есть вкладка публикация (Publishing), она вторая слева.
В ней есть поля

- Meta Description
- Meta Keywords
- Key Reference
- Robots
- External Reference

Так что из коробки все присутствует в менеджере материалов.

А если этого действительно нету, тогда идете в меню **Content->Articles**

```
/administrator/index.php?option=com_config&view=component&component=com_content
```

На этой странице жмете кнопку **Options**, переходите на вкладку **Editing Layout** (она вторая) и в ней включаете опцию **Show Publishing Options** (она первая)

Comment: Вроде все стоит, но как то все равно в материалах, я этого не увидел, буду копать. Спасибо!

Comment: Всем кому интересно, я воспользовался сторонним плагином K2 Page Title Plugin . Теперь можно и title и заголовок делать разными.